# module 'dtale' has no attribute 'global_state'

Tags: python, data-science

I installed the dtale library with !pip install dtale in jupyter notebook then I ran the next command import dtale.
But am getting this error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1fc5e15a58d6> in <module>()
----> 1 import dtale 

E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtale\__init__.py in <module>()
      4 
      5 # flake8: NOQA
----> 6 from dtale.app import show, get_instance, instances, offline_chart  # isort:skip
      7 from dtale.cli.loaders import LOADERS  # isort:skip
      8 

E:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dtale\app.py in <module>()
     22 from six import PY3
     23 
---> 24 import dtale.global_state as global_state
     25 from dtale import dtale
     26 from dtale.cli.clickutils import retrieve_meta_info_and_version, setup_logging

AttributeError: module 'dtale' has no attribute 'global_state'
```

Comment: Have you tried to install it via conda-forge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output it looks like you installed it within an anaconda environment which sometimes doesn't play well with pip.

- I'd try uninstalling: `pip uninstall dtale`
- Then re-install using conda-forge: `conda install dtale -c conda-forge`